# Drupal Theme editing

Tags: css, drupal, admin

Hey I accepted a drupal project, I am experience with PHP, HTML, but not so much Drupal.  I am editing the look of the page.  So not to much php is needed.  However I was provided the ftp and site drupal admin. How do I go about editing css, as of now the ftp file are read-only, and I cannot edit them.  Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Drupal works from themes.

1. ftp into your site
2. find the "themes" folder where you installed Drupal
3. each theme will be in it's own folder ie: garland, bluemarine etc.
4. open appropriate theme
5. depending on the theme you should see a style.css file
6. drag the file down, edit and put back online!

done!

Edit: also I should note, that if you are wanting to edit the CSS from the Drupal Admin it's really only supported on a per theme basis. So if that theme has this built in. I know some themes do, Fusion and Zen.

Comment: I'm assuming that if i have a username and password for the ftp, I should have read access. Is there a command that I need to use to be able to write to ftp, or does ftp have user management variables?  I see a drush folder, is that a command line that may be restricting this?

Comment: I haven't worked with Drush in particular but I have read about it before. It's a command line tool for updating Drupal. It could be the culprit causing the locked files. I have seen Drush in the past used on Drupal Multi-sites. In theory with your FTP access you should be able to Get and Put the css files. You may want to right click and check the CHMOD permissions on the style.css files. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

You should have an FTP write access. At least for sites/all/themes folder, where You should put Your custom theme.